# How to throw Error of type FirebaseError

Tags: angular, firebase, error-handling

I have a situation where I need to throw an error. The error must match [FirebaseError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.FirebaseError) interface.

I tried to import this interface

```
import { FirebaseError } from '@firebase/util';
```

But I don't know how to use it

```
throw new FirebaseError ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirebaseError`is an interface. You should create your custom error class that extends from `FirebaseError` and throw it:

```
class FirebaseSignInError extends FirebaseError {
}
```

After that, just call:

`throw new FirebaseSignInError`

Comment: Thanks it worked. `throw new FirebaseSignInError('code', 'message');`

Comment: For the TypeScript users its `class FirebaseErrorTest implements FirebaseError {...}`